# Firebase firestore onSnapshot not picking up changes and rendering on ReactJs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We have a ReactJs application which used Firebase. When you first register for the application and you log in for the first time, the app loads a document from Firebase using the `onSnapshot` method, and renders a component that uses the data in the view. The problem is, when we make changes to the loaded document and those changes are written back to Firebase, the ReactJs application isn't picking up that those changes have been applied and so the view isn't updated. If however, we refresh the app, the changes we've made are rendered and future changes are picked up as normal and everything is fine.

Here is the code where we are calling the `onSnapshot` method. You can see I've stuck some debugging text in there, this is only rendered once when the document is not loaded, so I know that the problem is that this isn't picking up the document changes in firestore.

```
function useHub(hubId) {
  console.debug("useHub");
  const Firebase = React.useContext(FirebaseContext);

  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);
  const [hub, setHub] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.debug("useHub: useEffect");
    setHub(null);
    console.log('****************************');
    console.log("Hub ID " + hubId);
    if (hubId) {
      const unsubscribe = Firebase.firestore()
        .collection("hubs")
        .doc(hubId)
        .onSnapshot(
          (doc) => {
            const hubDoc = Object.assign({}, { id: doc.id }, doc.data());

            console.log('***************************');
              console.log('***************************');
                console.log(hubDoc);
              console.log('***************************');
              console.log('***************************');

            setHub(hubDoc);
            setLoading(false);
            setError(false);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
            setError(error.message);
            setLoading(false);
          }
        );

      return () => unsubscribe();
    }
  }, [Firebase, hubId]);

  return {
    loading,
    error,
    hub,
  };
}

export { useHub };
```

What are the possible reasons why this would be occuring?

Comment: How are you refreshing your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider to have your component update itself as a workaround. I have found this document [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), which describes the details.